# Get RTSP stream on server from WebRTC

Tags: streaming, webrtc, rtsp

How can I get RTSP stream on server from WebRTC and then use it for my own purposes, for example, to retranslate it somewhere. Maybe there is some solution or library?

Any help is much appreciated!
Denis

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are willing to hook into the webrtc code then this can be done easily by doing the following:

1. Build a native webrtc C++ client on server
2. If the codec used is H.264, tap the output (encoded frames) from H264 RTP receiver.
3. Use a third party library such as (http://www.live555.com/openRTSP/) to build a RTSP server out of it.

If vp8, you might as well tap the output of vp8 decoder and then use ffmpeg to create rtsp stream out of it. Or consider webm may be?

Comment: So there is no simplier solution? Maybe some library or media server like Kurento Media Server?

Comment: Yeah media server is the best bet

Comment: @Denis, did you manage to do this? Can you give some details of your implementation?

Comment: @manishg, what do you mean by "tap" the output? I have an H264 encoded webrtc connection but I don't know how to get that RTP stream and forward it.

Comment: If you are building Webrtc, you can then tap the same from the decoder output. However please check as we may have some open source projects which might as well be doing this now